# Parsing Simulink models

Tags: java, parsing, simulink

We are looking for a library to parse Simulink model. We have found a python library but no Java solution. Are there any open source libraries that can parse Simulink 2012a models?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try ConQAT (Continuous Quality Assessment Toolkit) [ConQAT Simulink Library](http://conqat.in.tum.de/index.php/Simulink_Library).

Comment: That link is broken; here's the current one: https://www.cqse.eu/en/products/simulink-library-for-java/overview/